Как изменить конфигурационный файл в контейнере до запуска в Kubernetes?
Есть некий сервис в котором пароль задается в текстовом файле. Этот файл находится в docker контейнере. К сожалению переменные среды для задания пароля не используются. Как изменить этот файл ДО того как сервис запустится в среде kubernetes? Я так думаю нужен какой то init контейнер который перед запуском заменит значение. так ли это? Есть ли более простой путь?

Примонтируйте этот файл с хоста либо модифицируйте скрпитом при старте контейнера.

А куда монтировать? На локальную файловую систему? И как тогда изменить?

На локальную файловую систему. Изменяете в любом текстовом редакторе.
